# SSRS 2008 R2 Chart Series Tooltip Accuracy

Tags: tooltip, ssrs-2008-r2, linechart

I have a (Smooth Lines with Markers) type Chart in one of my reports and I added the total that drives the line as the series tooltip.

At first glance everything works great, but I soon realized that the accuracy of the tooltip seems a bit finicky.

Example: The top middle marker on the picture is from March and it's total is 22,347,982.29, the lower point to it's right is from April and it's total is 21,637,486.27 and the lower point on the far left is from February with a total of 21,664,117.94

The black dot on each red marker represents the location of the cursor when the screenshot was taken. Notice how if my cursor is on the right side of the top March marker, the tooltip shows 21,637,486.28 which as actually the value from the month of April (the bottom right marker). But if I move my cursor just to the left of the marker's middle (Figure B) the tooltip correctly shows 22,347,982.29. The same goes for the far left February marker, I have to put my cursor towards the bottom left of the marker for it to show February's 21,664,117.94 value

[image: Chart Example]

I increased the marker size for my screenshots, the published report has a marker size of 4.5pts, this makes it rather difficult to correctly place the cursor correctly to see the correct tooltip amount.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this before too.

The tooltip relies on the pixel position to determine which month the user is referring too. Unfortunately, half the marker is in the previous month.

Maybe the best solution is to set the marker to 1 point or just get rid of the marker altogether?